# JQ: check if substring from key exists in an array

Tags: json, jq

I have an array of objects as input, each object looking as follows:

```
{
  "downloadDir": "/merge/downloads",
  "id": 2485,
  "labels": [
    "irrelevant",
    "downloads"
  ]
}
```

I am trying to have JQ go through every object and find those, which do not have an element in the .labels array that is a substring of .downloadDir between 1st and 2nd '/', i.e.

- for "/merge/downloads" it should be "downloads"
- for "/merge/tv/downloads" it should be "tv"
- for "/merge/tv-share/downloads" it should be "tv-share"

For matching objects it should return their .id.

Having reviewed some similar questions on Stack Overflow, I'm thinking the logic is supposed to look something like this: map(select(.labels | index(.downloadDir))). This works if I have a static string in index(), like map(select(.labels | index("downloads"))), however I can't get it to work with .downloadDir: it throws out "Cannot index array with string "downloadDir"" or "Cannot index string with string "labels"", depending on whether I pass the input as an array or not.

I am entirely unsure how to approach applying a regex to .downloadDir to grab the needed substring from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split the `.downloadDir` at `"/"` using `/`, and take the second item. Compare it to each item in `.labels` and yield `true` if at least one (`any`) matches. `select` those items, and output the `.id`.

```bash
jq 'select(any(.labels[] == (.downloadDir / "/")[2]; .)).id ' input.json
```

```json
2485
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/vOtVsc7WbzM)

This works on a stream of items (as suggested by your sample). If your input is indeed an array of items, prepend `.[]`.

Comment: Thank you. I needed a list of items that do not match the criteria, however adding a "| not" seems to have done it for me: .[] | select(any(.labels[] == (.downloadDir / "/")[2]; .) | not).id

Comment: Instead of appending `| not`, you can also just select all items that don't match, i.e. change `any` to `all`, and `==` to `!=`.

Answer (score 0):

I added one more object into the input for testing:

```
[{
  "downloadDir": "/merge/downloads",
  "id": 2485,
  "labels": [
    "irrelevant",
    "downloads"
  ]
},{
  "downloadDir": "/merge/tv/downloads",
  "id": 2486,
  "labels": [
    "irrelevant",
    "downloads"
  ]
}]
```

The following expression returned the `id` of the first object, not the second:

```
<file.json jq '.[]
               | (.downloadDir | split("/")[2]) as $key
               | select(.labels | map(. != $key) | all).id'
```

Comment: Thank you. However, this seems to return .id of matched objects, instead of unmatched objects and I'm having a bit of trouble reversing the result.

Comment: Sorry, missed the detail. Updated.